# I need a count of each track sold in an album then display all album names and it's corresponding track name that has max count in sql

Tags: sql, count, max

sales table shows how many of each track is sold. I need to count of each track sold
album table shows album names common field is trackid
I need album name, only track title that's sold max in that album and count of that track sold.

```
select al.title as album, t.name as track, max(s.sales)
from tracks t, albums al, 
    (select al.title as album, count(i.trackid) as sales 
    from albums al, tracks t, invoice_items i
    where t.trackid = i.trackid and t.albumid = al.albumid
    group by album)s
where t.albumid = al.AlbumId;
```

Comment: Which dbms is being used? Please add that as a tag. SQL has many differences between the various db vendors. e.g. MySQL, Oracle, Postgres all differ in their SQL syntax

Comment: Don't rely on words to convey your meaning I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)